# Is there any way to select specific a tags using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup and trying to print all a tag href which contains only companies website url. But my code is selecting other href too. There are total 71 companies website links but my code is not selecting all those href.
This is the [source](https://www.constructionplacements.com/top-construction-companies-in-india-2020/) from where I'm extracting data

Here is my **code**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.constructionplacements.com/top-construction-companies-in-india-2020/'

name_data = []
website_data = []

print(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

# Loop to select and print all companies title
for h in soup.select('h4'):
    print(h.text)
    name_data.append(h.text)

# Loop to select and print all companies website url
for w in soup.select('p em a'):
    print(w['href'])
    website_data.append(w['href'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Company Title': name_data,
    'Website': website_data
})
print(df)

df.to_csv('ata.csv')
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Pandas? Please only include relevant tags.

Comment: @noah I am using panda to save it in csv form

Comment: Please phrase your question as a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you needed to edit to add the code that makes includes Pandas then it must be unrelated to your problem. Adding the Pandas info just makes it harder for you to get an answer as the question is now has additional, unnecessary, complications.

Comment: @noah you're right. Thank you from next time i'll make sure to use more relevant tags :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all links to companies, you can use this example:

```
import re
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.constructionplacements.com/top-construction-companies-in-india-2020/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for h4 in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name=='h4' and re.search(r'^\d+\s*\.', t.text)):
    print('{:<75} {}'.format(h4.text, h4.find_next('a')['href']))
```

Prints:

```
1. L&T Engineering & Construction Division (L&T ECC), Chennai               http://www.lntecc.com/
2. Tata Projects Ltd, Mumbai                                                http://www.tataprojects.com/
3. Shapoorji Pallonji & Co Ltd, Mumbai                                      https://www.shapoorjipallonji.com/
4. GMR Group, Mumbai                                                        http://www.gmrgroup.in/
5. Hindustan Construction Company (HCC), Mumbai                             http://www.hccindia.com/
6. Afcons Infrastructure Limited, Mumbai                                    http://www.shapoorjipallonji.com/
7. JMC Projects, Mumbai                                                     https://www.jmcprojects.com/
8. Gammon India Ltd, Mumbai                                                 http://www.gammonindia.com
9. IVRCL, Hyderabad                                                         http://www.ivrcl.com/
10. J Kumar Infra, Mumbai                                                   http://www.jkumar.com/
11. Gammon Infrastructure Projects Limited (GIPL), Mumbai                   http://www.gammoninfra.com/
12. Reliance Infrastructure                                                 http://www.rinfra.com
13. Ashoka Buildcon, Nashik                                                 https://ashokabuildcon.com/
14. B L Kashyap & Sons Ltd (BLK), New Delhi                                 http://www.blkashyap.com
15. Consolidated Construction Consortium Ltd (CCCL), Chennai                http://www.ccclindia.com/
16. Essar Group, Mumbai                                                     https://www.essar.com/

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't knew that we can use regex too with BeautifulSoup.